# Javascript SetMonth Issue

Tags: javascript, date, dst

I am doing unit tests.

```js
  it("Month calculate", () => {
    const baseDate = new Date("2015-02-15T12:00:00.000Z");
    baseDate.setMonth(baseDate.getMonth() + 1)
    expect(baseDate.toISOString()).toBe("2015-03-15T12:00:00.000Z")
  })
```

**On my local node process I get this error**

```
Expected: "2015-03-15T12:00:00.000Z"
Received: "2015-03-15T13:00:00.000Z"
```

**On docker node process it works.**

I believe it is related to the DST, but I don't understand how...

Comment: What timezone are you in. Would you expect DST to come in to effect between 15th February and 15th March.

Comment: @phuzi my timezone is GMT-3, "Brasilia Standard Time"

Comment: @phuzi - On this is fun. They don't use DST anymore, but they did until 2019, and the change in 2015 was on 22nd Feb - https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia?year=2015 :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Indeed, there are so many more questions. But the issue appears to be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that DST is coming into play, because you're using the **local time** `setMonth`/`getMonth` methods, so DST comes into it (adding the month, the `Date` object takes DST into account to avoid changing the time-of-day; but when you look at the result in UTC, you see the time is off by the DST offset, since it was local time math that applied to the increment). To work in UTC like the rest of your code, use `setUTCMonth`/`getUTCMonth` instead.

```
it("Month calculate", () => {
    const baseDate = new Date("2015-02-15T12:00:00.000Z");
    baseDate.setUTCMonth(baseDate.getUTCMonth() + 1)
    expect(baseDate.toISOString()).toBe("2015-03-15T12:00:00.000Z")
})
```

Likely your docker node is working UTC, or at least in a time zone where DST doesn't change during that month (it doesn't here in the UK, for instance; we don't change until later in March). But in your local timezone, apparently DST occurs during that month, so you see the issue locally but not on the docker node.